# The Auth password reset link sent by email is wrong

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, url, laravel-5

The link that I receive to the email to reset my password is not well formed:

should be:

http://localhost:8000/password/reset/sometoken

but instead I receive

http://localhost/password/reset/sometoken

the other routes of Auth work well, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Give your code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `APP_URL` variable in `.env` file. It should contain the host where your application is available and will be used to generate any absolute URLs you generate.

Comment: Thats it! This solved the problem... I dont know why the other routes worked perfectly and this problem only happened with the reset password...

Comment: Other routes don't use absolute URLs, so they don't contain the host part.